# Haproxy equivalent to this nginx config (server_name)

Tags: nginx, haproxy

imagine this config in nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }
}
```

how can i describe "server_name" in haproxy config ?
should it be like this? :

```
frontend example_frontend
   ...
   use_backend     example_backend if { ... "check server_name here?" ... }
   ...
```